# Firebase admin sdk throws X509 errors inside Kubernetes pod

Tags: firebase, go, kubernetes, sdk, x509certificate

I am getting x509 error inside a kubernetes pod. Running it locally it works perfectly and when i deploy it to a server it throws x509 errors.

My theory is that maybe internal kubernetes DNS is messing this up and i havent configured it correctly.
Can anyone point me to a possible solution?

```
Get \"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com\": x509: certificate is valid for cloudfront.net, *.cloudfront.net, not www.googleapis.com
```

I have tried inside my alpine image

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates && update-ca-certificates
```

```golang
token, err := firebaseAuth.VerifyIDToken(context.Background(), idToken)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Getting same issue on Debian bullseye.